# Why do some SMD electrolytic capacitors have platforms?

Tags: surface-mount, electrolytic-capacitor

I’m working on a computer monitor’s power board (to replace a capacitor or two, which I assume is the problem), and found these:

[image: board with caps]

Replacements are easy to find, so no issues there, but I’m curious why the SMD aluminum electrolytic capacitors are on little platforms (or spacers). To buffer swelling maybe?

[image: stock smd image]

Comment: Isolating the metal case from traces/pads that may run underneath it. This is really  only a problem for SMD caps, the lead-style ones naturally have a buffer due to the leads.

Comment: With the faulty capacitors you have removed carefully remove the base.  What can you see.<br> I suspect the casing could touch both pads on the PCB and is conductive.

Comment: @WarrenHill Probably right. I’ll take a look when I remove them. I had to order some replacements, so I left them on the board for the time being.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those capacitors are really made similarly to the cylindrical radial lead through-hole capacitors. Two connections come out through a rubber bung (in an aluminum case that is crimped at the bottom to form a seal) and those leads are bend to form SMT leads.

From [this](https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/lib/new112.html) Nichicon website (a conductive polymer type is shown, and conventional electrolytics are similar):

[image]

The plastic base is just there to provide physical support for the capacitor can so it doesn't flop around too much on the leads.

Answer (score 2):

The base is for support plus when soldering it is a large object which would insulate heat. Same if you ever had to solder a ball grid array chip. Also these bigger capacitor are normally connected to a power connection again soaking heat away.

Comment: How does a plastic base "soak heat away" from the capacitor? Are you saying that a BGA chip has (or should have) a plastic base?